# How to use H1 in table headings in Laravel Excel

Tags: laravel-excel

When exporting Blade views using Laravel Excel, I can use a `<h1>` tag and it works fine unless I use it within a table cell.

If I use it within a table cell the content is output, but without the formatting.  I realise I could listen for an event, then format the headings myself, but it would be far more convenient if Laravel Excel did it out of the box.  Can it?